# SQL Injection with long data type

Tags: sql-injection

All the examples of an SQL injections that I've seen have a user controlled `string` variable that was directly used to construct the SQL query but, I was wondering if it's possible to perform an SQL injection provided that the variable `userNumber` is a `long` and is user-controlled in the following query.

```
sqlQuery='SELECT * FROM custTable WHERE UserNumber=' + UserNumber;
```

I understand that using a parameterized query is the best option to prevent an SQL injection attack but I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will rely mostly on how your backend (application code not DB) behaves.
If the application `cast()`  or rejects everything but `longs`  (or `ints` or whatever numeric types) there is simply no chance you can conduct a successful injection.

If your application doesn't sanitize user input your example could be SQL injectable:

```
sqlQuery='SELECT * FROM custTable WHERE UserNumber=' + 22 UNION SELECT ...;
```